# How do a model's size, depth and number of parameters affect training time?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have found a table describing the size, depth and number of parameters for every model supported by the Keras.Applications module (https://keras.io/applications/ under "Documentation for individual models"). I want to choose a model based on it's accuracy compared to how long it might take to train

I assume the number of parameters directly influences training time, because the more parameters you have the more computationally difficult the gradient descent will be. But some Models, especially VGG16, have a lot of parameters and a very low depth. Or DenseNet121 and Xception, both have very similary depth but very different number of parameters and size in MB.

Do the size and depth also influence how long it takes to train? And if so, in what way? Does training time scale linearly with number of parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depth is less of an issue, but number of parameters matters a lot, and something you don't mention, the size of *inputs* matters a lot too.

First of all, if you are using vision networks, then you probably have a lot of convolution layers. If you feed a ***300 x 300*** image to your network, and let's say the first layer is a ***3 x 3*** kernel convolution with stride ***2***, output channels ***100***, then network will run the ***300 x 300*** kernel on the whole image, doing ***150 x 150 x 3 x 3 x 100 = 20,250,000*** calculations for forward propagation even though a ***3 x 3*** kernel has ***9*** parameters only, so with ***100*** output channels you have ***900***, which is a miniscule number.

Different layers also have different computational requirements. A dropout layer is super cheap, for example. A logit or softmax is much more expensive. Batch normalization also adds a lot as it has to calculate the standard deviation for the activations, which requires a lot of squaring. Relu is again, super cheap, it's invention was one of the main factors allowing the breakthrough in computer vision in 2014. Think about it this way: addition is ultra cheap. Multiplication is cheap. Anything involving logarithm or exponentiation is expensive. (Squaring can be cheap if done as a multiplication.) Gradient calculation is done based on taking the derivative, so whatever operation you have for forward propagation, also think about what it's derivative is, because that will determine the time requirement for backward propagation.

Training time is even more tricky to estimate because a well-tuned hyperparameter set (learning rate, learning rate annealment, etc.) has a lot of influence over that, and different architectures have different optima for them.

Furthermore, this is all assuming that the infrastructure under the network is not a bottleneck. If you cannot fetch the input quickly enough from disk (or memory, if you have enough, and prefetch and cache the data) or the PCI-E bus cannot handle the data transfer quickly enough (especially in multi-GPU environments), then that will adversely affect training time too. If you're using a cloud service, then you might not even have the info how it's set up.

All in all, I hope I gave you some pointers. But I'm afraid I can't really save you the trouble of experimentation, except for some really clear-cut cases.